# Data format - convert to new format

Tags: java, string

How can I format string like this:

`"8:00- 8:45"`

to

`"08:00-08:45"`

I think I should use something like data formatter but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: `String str = "8:00- 8:45".replace(" ");`

Comment: @YCF_L `replace(..)` expects two arguments...

Comment: @YCF_L it's not what is wanted: see the leading zeros in the wanted result string

Comment: ooops i don't see it

Comment: @fantaghirocco: yes it is possible to do that in java. Please refrain from commenting like that. Each knw: From were do you get the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use regex like this :

```
String str = "8:00- 8:45";
str = str.replace(" ", "").replaceAll("(\\b\\d\\b)", "0$1");
System.out.println(str);//outputs 08:00-08:45
```

details

- first `.replace(" ", "")` will remove all the spaces
- second you can use [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to put 0 before each unique degit, in your case before `8` -> `08` in strings like `8:3- 08:5` -> `08:03-08:05` [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvaBca/1)